# Remove an NSNotification observer that may not exist

Tags: objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I can not seem to find a definitive answer on this topic.

Is it okay to remove an observer that may not exist?

Example Code:

```
-(void)commonInit{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                        selector:@selector(userDidChangePrecision:)
                                            name:kUser_Changed_Precision
                                          object:nil];

 } 


-(void)dealloc{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self];

    [super dealloc];

}
```

This would prevent more than one observer being initialized for the object in the case where the object may be reinitialized during run time.

Comment: Seems odd to call *commonInit* more than once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snippet from the Apple docs:

```
- (void)removeObserver:(id)notificationObserver
    Parameters
    *notificationObserver*
        The observer to remove. Must not be nil.

- (void)removeObserver:(id)notificationObserver name:(NSString *)notificationName object:(id)notificationSender
    Parameters
    *notificationObserver*
        Observer to remove from the dispatch table. Specify an observer to remove only entries for this observer. Must not be nil, or message will have no effect.
```

In both cases, the warning that observer not be nil is overstated; the effect, in both cases, is that this message has no effect.  Neither compiler nor runtime errors, no zombies, &c.

Likewise, specifying an observer that is not observing also has no effect.

**Not a definitive answer**, but based on observations and investigations of playing with trial-and-error code such as:

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:nil];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:[UIView new]];`

Comment: You could add a flag to your potential observer *isObserving*.. This could be added via a category + *objc_[set|get]AssociatedObject* if it's not a class defined in your code.

Comment: @nielsbot, that's quite neat.

Comment: It's most likely reasonable to assume it is okay then ?

Comment: @Miek I am a total stranger to you, but I care about my projects and if we were pair-programming, I would tell you it's okay; but to be certain, it's not the actual definite answer you asked for.

Answer (score 3):

I can't find definitive documentation on if it's allowed to remove non-existent observers but I think the `NSNotificationCenter` documentation can be read in this way. It says that `removeObserver:name:object:` removes *matching* observers. I'm just assuming that this includes *no* matching observers.

But here's another reason why your approach might be harmful: When your `commonInit` method is being called other code (sub- or superclasses' init) might already have registered to notifications. When subclassing a `UIViewController` that's even likely (for memory warnings).

So I'd say you should never unconditionally unregister from notification center, except in dealloc.